# What's the type for radio button?

Tags: html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, phpmyadmin, radio-button

I'm creating a database using XAMPP localhost. My problem is that I don't know what's the type of radio button in DB. please help me to solve it

Here's my code :

```html
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label style="margin-top: 3px" class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Priority</label>
    <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="priority" id="high" value="">High</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="priority" id="medium" value="">Medium</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="priority" id="low" value="">Low</label>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Enum datatype you can use : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: I have improved the formatting of your code block by correcting the indentations. Well formatted code is easier to read and debug. I have also removed the tool names from title because they are not required and can be added as part of tags. Finally, I have replaced the bootstrap tag with twitter-bootstrap because I think that is what you are using. Bootstrap tag points to something else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to build a form to submit to a database, so a `radio`button is just a `radio` button as far as type goes.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioOne" value="yes">Yes <br> <input type="radio" name="radioOne" value="no">No
```

Are you referring to your form or whats being submitted to the db?

Comment: i refer to submit it to the db

Comment: Can you expand on your question and add any details that may better explain the problem you're having?